# Assigned dimension to values in Python

Tags: python, python-xarray

I tried:

```
x = xr.DataArray(x, coords=[ lat_line, lon_line], dims=[ 'lat','lon'])
```

with x is array, (array([1.47937608e-01, 6.56879655e-01, ..., 2.91481077e-01); lat, lon, lat_line, lon_line is already defined with the same elements. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your x should be 2D if you declare 2 dimensions.
I think it could work if you remove the dims declaration part.
lat and lon will then be coordinate but not dimensions.

But it will be easier to handle if you have lat & lon as dimensions (if you want to average by coordinate bins or like that). I don't know if xarray can build the cube itself.